# What users are capable of if safety rules are not specified in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am working with log-in log-out management, and it turns out that it's quite important to use the FirebaseAuth for all operations. But since only I have the service account key and only I can alter how the app is working, I'm wondering how someone can read or write in my database other than what I've programmatically given to them within the app. Can someone help explaining this to me? I would be really glad.

Comment: Your database comes with exactly one rule when you create it.  It either allows all access for all users, or allows all access to only authenticated users.  Please edit the question to show which rule you chose at the time you created your database.  Service accounts do no apply in this case.

Comment: @DougStevenson, what I'm trying to ask is how bad it can be if I leave it for unauthenticated users too. Can someone supposedly break in to my Firestore documents elsewhere than the app?

Comment: You might be interested in reading the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811142/is-it-acceptable-to-leave-a-database-cloud-firestore-unsecured-when-no-site-lo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your security rules allow access to unauthenticated users, then anyone with an internet connection will be able to read and write the entire contents of your database.  It will be especially easy with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api).

A judgement of how "bad" that is for your project is entirely up to you to determine.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer, I am sorry for my unclear question and the lack of research. I think I got better understanding of how exactly someone from outside can access the database now. By the way, I found your videos about google cloud functions to be very useful. Want to thank you for that as well.